# Can a non-symmetrical colour gradient range be customised to define 0 (+-1) as a particular colour?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've tried to use ggplot2 to create a dotplot grid to visualise average fold change of transcriptomic pathways at particular ages. I've tried using both `scale_fill_gradientn` and `scale_color_gradient2`. The `scale_color_gradient2` approach was good as it allowed definition of a midpoint. However, the colour of the midpoint didn't allow for the lower values (-47 to 0) to be differentiated from 0 fold change:

```
scale_color_gradient2(
    low = "blue",
    mid = "green",
    high = "red",
    midpoint = 0,   
    aesthetics = "color")
```

This is what happens when I use `scale_color_gradient2`:

[image]

When using `scale_fill_gradientn`, I start to see the lower values differentiating from the green, but still having difficulty differentiating the lower values from 0:

```
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("blue","green","orange","red"),
                       values = rescale(c(-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1)),
                       na.value = "grey50",
                       aesthetics = "color",
                       name = 'Fold Change')
```

This is what the scale looks like when I use `scale_fill_gradientn`:

[image]

I did try adding a line for limits, however  this did not get the results I want. I've also tried adding breaks, and values/rescaling was not working for me the way I wanted it to.

What I do want is a scale range from -47 to 163, with the -47 end displaying the deep blue colour, and the 163 end with the bright red, and the green band to be at 0 with no diffusion out (so say a green band from -1 to 1 on the scale). I couldn't find a way to define the midpoint as a range (that worked) using the `scale_color_gradient2` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a matter of choosing an appropriate vector of `values=` and/or `colors=`, e.g. in the code below I specified the range from -1 to 1 to be displayed as `"green"`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = 1, y = 1, color = 100)) +
  scale_color_gradientn(
    colours = c("blue", "green", "green", "orange", "red"),
    values = scales::rescale(
      c(-47, -1, 0, 1, 82, 163)
    ),
    na.value = "grey50",
    name = "Fold Change",
    limits = c(-47, 163)
  )
```

[image]